# How to send a websocket message from a non-async method?

Tags: python, websocket, gpiozero

I am using [these docs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) to get to know `websockets` from Python.

When everything that is happening 'inside' those `async` methods, it works fine, but how can I send a message outside of that? In my specific example, I am getting a `button_pressed` event from a GPIO pin on a Raspberry PI, and I want to send all connected users a message that that button was pressed:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import gpiozero

USERS = set()

def button_pressed():
    print("Doorbell rang!")
    if USERS:
        for user in USERS:
            print(f"Sending ring to {user}")
            asyncio.wait(user.send("ring"))

button = gpiozero.Button(3)
button.when_pressed = button_pressed

def register(ws):
    USERS.add(ws)

def unregister(ws):
    USERS.remove(ws)

async def doorbellsocket(websocket, path):
    register(websocket)

    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            print(f"Received message: {message}. Ignored.")
    finally:
        unregister(websocket)
    
print(f"Starting doorbellserv on {settings.host}:{settings.port}")
start_server = websockets.serve(doorbellsocket, settings.host, settings.port)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The code runs, the button press event gets fired and Python says it sends something, but nothing arrives in my client, which is as simple as this:

```
function connectToServ() {
    var socket = new WebSocket(url);
    console.log("Connected to "+socket)
    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    }; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have to so `asyncio.run`:

```
def button_pressed():
    print("Doorbell rang!")

    if USERS:
        for user in USERS:
            print(f"Sending ring to {user}")
            asyncio.run(user.send("ring"))
```